# Choosing a D3 Data Visualization

Tags: d3.js, bigdata, data-visualization, information-visualization

I am working on a project and I need to visualize my results. As I look at the sample visualizations available with D3, I wonder if there are any guidelines to choose the best data visualization that best fits your data?

I have already tried Matrix Co-occurence visualization.

My data format:
key1 : V21, V22, V23....V2n
key2 : V21, V22, V23....V2n
... ... ... ... ... ... 
keyn : Vn1, Vn2, Vn3....Vnm

Can anyone please suggest some D3 visualizations that I can try for my data in this format?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can you please share a sample data or the use case to suggest you the best d3 chart suitable for your use case. You can even check http://pykcharts.js if any of it fits best in your use case

Comment: Well I have a mapping between document names and the keywords that represents those documents - like doc_cricket : bat, ball, batsman, fielder, umpire   doc_football : football, players, referee and so on. There are thousands of documents (around 70K) and each has on an average 4 keywords associated with it.

Comment: Can you categorize the 70K documents. Loading 70K nodes in browser will drastically reduce the performance. So there can be a filter which will load only fewer documents

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest to you two charts with I already used in a project :

1 - http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html

2 - http://nvd3.org/examples/line.html.

The data to give is similar to your formats (maybe you need to change a little your data) but the result is pretty cool :)